# Which will be returned in a program

Tags: java

I was wondering what will be returned in a java program when you have multiple returns in a program.

```
private int numberReturner()
{
    if (a) return a;
    else if (b) return b;
    for (int i = 1; i < board.size()-1; i++)
    {
        if (c) return c;
    }
    return d;
}
```

So lets say a is true, (it should return a), but wouldn't it return d because that is the final line of code in the whole program? Why is this so?

Sorry if I worded this a bit strangely...

Comment: You can always run/debug to check it.

Comment: It's absolutely an obvious thing. Where were you confusing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once any 'return' statement is encountered the method will exit execution and return that value.

That method will return d only if no other return statement is encountered before reaching that last line.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will make sure to make this my answer in 10 minutes :)

Comment: Absolutely - glad I could help to clarify!

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the first "return" encountered will be the one returned. But if there is a "return" statement encountered in a finally block, the "return" in the finally block will be returned.
e.g.

```
private int m1(){
    try{
        return 1;
    }finally{
        return 2; //this will be returned instead
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've already "returned" you are never going to hit the subsequent returns.

Answer (score 1):

The method returns a because the return statement exits from the current method, and control flow returns to where the method was invoked. Please read more about different branching keywords in Java tutorial. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 1):

Once a `return` statement is executed the method ends and if it is not `void` the return value is returned.

I know only one exception to this rule, and you have it with the `finally` statement.
Take this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(test());
}

private static int test() {
    try {
        return 1;
    } finally {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

in this case `test()` returns 2, because the `finally` statement in this case is always executed before exit the method.

Answer (score 0):

The current execution thread will leave a method the first time it encounters a `return` statement (the notable exception to this rule is with `try...finally` blocks, where, once a `return` is encountered, the `finally{...}` block executes before leaving the method.